# Are non-PL manifolds CW-complexes?

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

Can every topological (not necessarily smooth or PL) manifold be given the structure of a CW complex?

I'm pretty sure that the answer is yes.  However, I have not managed to find a reference for this.

Comment: @algori : I thought you had posted an (important sounding) comment?  Why did you delete it?

Comment: It turns out that my first comment was a bit wrong. Here are the slides of A. Ranicki's talk in Orsay. www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/slides/orsay.pdf It says on p. 5 there that a compact manifold of dimension other than 4 is a CW complex.

There is a related conjecture that says that each closed manifold of dimension $\geq 5$ is homeomorphic to a polyhedron (there are 4-manifolds for which this is false). See arxiv.org/pdf/math/0212297.

I'm not sure what if anything is known about the noncompact case.

Comment: Update: recent work of Davis, Fowler, and Lafont http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/1304.3730 shows that in every dimension ≥6 there exists a closed aspherical manifold that is not homeomorphic to a simplicial complex.

Comment: Hatcher's Algebraic Topology p. 529 has a paragraph answering this question very clearly for compact manifolds (not including results in 2013 of course). However his references are to two long dense books, without page specification.

Answer (score 15):

Kirby and Siebenmann's paper "On the triangulation of manifolds and the Hauptvermutung" Bull AMS 75 (1969) is the standard reference for this, I believe.

The result is that compact topological manifolds have the homotopy-type of CW-complexes, to be precise.

Comment: I think the fact that they have the homotopy type of a CW complex is due to Milnor (it is in his paper about spaces homotopy equivalent to CW complexes). Do Kirby-Siebenmann just prove this, or do they prove that all compact manifolds are homeomorphic to CW complexes? Also, how about the noncompact case? 

Comment: But I thought the question was whether each has the "homeomorphism type" of a CW complex.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at that Milnor paper -- I suspect maybe he's arguing that manifolds have the homotopy-type of countable CWs, while Kirby-Siebenmann deal with compact manifolds and finite CWs.  ?

Comment: @Ryan : Yes, I think that is what Milnor proved (it's also been a long time since I looked at it).

Comment: @Dev, yes, that sounds right.  As algori mentions that's apparently an open problem.  As far as I know that problem hasn't attracted a whole lot of attention.  

Comment: @Ryan, the open problem is not whether any compact manifold is homeomorphic to a CW complex (this was proved by Kirby-Siebenmann). The open problem is whether it has a (non-combinatorial) triangulation. @grad student, whatever is known in the noncompact case must be Kirby-Siebenmann's book. 

Comment: @IgorBelegradek That doesn't sound right: The paper by Kirby-Siebenmann claims that they have the homotopy type of a CW complex, not that they are homeomorphic. Furthermore, [the answers to this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593041/cw-complexes-and-manifolds) seem to provide references that the case $n=4$ is still open. I don't know much (if anything) about these topics, but could you provide a reference to back up that claim?

Comment: @Danu: Kirby-Siebenmann's book  p.107: every closed topological manifold of dimension $\ge 6$ is homeomorphic to a CW complex. In the comment above I was of course talking about higher dimensions. The statement that every manifold (compact or not) is homotopy equivalent to a CW complex is much easier. For compact manifolds this is proved e.g. in Hatcher's textbook (in appendix on CW complexes).

Comment: @IgorBelegradek Thank you for the clarifications.

Answer (score 7):

See http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0609665

Comment: That manifold isn't 2nd countable. Like most mathematicians, I only care about manifolds that are Hausdorff and 2nd countable.

Comment: I hope that the fact that you only care about those does not preclude you from enjoying learning about the rest.