# Example of 4-manifold with $\pi_1=\mathbb Q$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, gt.geometric-topology, examples

This might be well known for algebraic topologist. So I am looking for an explicit example of a 4 dimensional manifold with fundamental group isomorphic to the rationals $\mathbb Q$.

Comment: What do you mean by "explicit"? You can take presentation complex for $Q$, immerse it in $R^4$ and then pull-back regular neighborhood. The result is your manifold.

Comment: See [this stackexchange question and answers.][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36775/is-the-group-of-rational-numbers-the-fundamental-group-of-some-space

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Since any compact manifold has the homotopy type of a finite CW-complex (see this MathOverflow question: [Are non-PL manifolds CW-complexes?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/36838/are-non-pl-manifolds-cw-complexes))  and $\mathbb{Q}$ is not finitely presented, the manifold $X$ you are looking for is necessarily non-compact.

An explicit construction of a non-compact *three*-manifold $M$ with $\pi_1(M)=\mathbb{Q}$   can be found in the paper

B. Evans and L. Moser: [*Solvable Fundamental Groups of Compact 3-Manifolds*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9947-1972-0301742-6), Transactions of the American Mathematical Society **168** (1972), see in particular page 209.

Now it suffices to take $X=M \times \mathbb{R}$.